# What is MVVM the VIEW first approach?

Tags: c#, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I'm learning MVVM in a course from Brian Lagunas in PluralSight.

At the beginning, he was writting this two interfaces:

```
public interface IView
{
    IViewModel ViewModel {get;set;}
}

public interface IViewModel
{
    IView View {get;set;}
}
```

I was learning in that mode, and then he removed ViewModel from IView.

```
public interface IView {}
```

But I can't see the difference of it, perhaps there's advantages and disadvantages of it.
Is anything wrong if I put the first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is of course to less context to leave any useful statements, but at first sight the interface

```
public interface IViewModel 
{
    IView View {get;set;}
}
```

seems very confusing for me because the main idea of the MVVM pattern is that the ViewModel is totally unaware of the View. If you equip the ViewModel with a reference to the View your are violating this idea.

Comment: So, you are purposing this context? public interface IView 
{ 
    IViewModel ViewModel {get;set;} 
} 
 
public interface IViewModel {}

Comment: "that the ViewModel is totally unaware of the View." - The _totally_ is not always practical or strictly necessary. Things like closing Windows and showing popups becomes very hard if you follow the 'pure' path.

Comment: I don't particularly agree with this statement. MVVM is more of a name to seperate parts of your application. There are no know or strict rules how to apply mvvm by saying "the ViewModel is totally unaware of the View". Then I would raise the question why the view CAN have a reference to the viewmodel. That doesnt make sense cause all you do is databind, commanding, and Notifications of properties being changed. This ofcourse all happens, as we know, with the datacontext.

Comment: @Rikkos: The View can and should have a link to the ViewModel because it is sitting on top of it and is using its services. Your are right, MVVM is a pattern that suggests a 3-tier architecture (View, View-Model, Model) but furthermore it says how to the layers have to be connected to each other in order to realize the actual strength of the pattern. Since the ViewModel is neither knowing of the existence nor the functionality (and in particular the implementation) of any View you can use several different Views with one ViewModel.

Comment: ... you may have a look here: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple)

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the information. I am aware of that and I was not sure about the reference of the viewmodel in the view. As far as I know the only reference/instance you need is the DataContext. So I dont see the point of having another field with viewmodel.

Comment: Rikkos, please correct me if i am wrong with that but for me the following holds: **ViewModel == DataContext** whereas "ViewModel" is the notion used in the **pattern-context** and "DataContext" is the notion used in the **WPF/Silverlight-context** where you implement the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/view-firstxaml-vs-viewmodel-firstdi-via-constructor/):

> - View-First: The View has a relationship to its ViewModel(usually
>     through data binding).
> - ViewModel-First: The ViewModel creates the view (usually through an
>     IoC container).
>
> In both of these methods it presents a sticky-ness of the view to the
>   view-model. Also, both of these imply a one-to-one relationship which
>   while the common case, is not the always case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't seen the pluralsight course, but I can talk generally about dependency management.  In the original scheme, you have entity A that knows about entity B and B that knows about A.  In this sense, there are two degrees of coupling:  A depends on B and B depends on A.  While they depend only on interfaces, which is a positive, that dependency still exists.

By removing one of those dependencies, you have a scenario where A depends on B, but B does not depend on, care about, or even know about A.  In the original scenario, if you make changes to IView or IViewModel's API, these will be breaking changes.  In the second scenario, you can make whatever changes you want to IViewModel and they will not affect the view implementations.

That's the advantage.

As for disadvantages, the only one is that you lose a convenience, but I consider that not really to be a disadvantage.  In my book, anytime you can minimize coupling and dependencies (within reason), that's a win.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's all about the idea to **abstract** the View through the ViewModel; the ViewModel exposes any property that must be presented to the View and the ones the View [user input in practice] can change (think to the two-way binding). It's the **binding engine** to take care through the PropertyChanged event to sync the UI  with the ViewModel; in this way the ViewModel does not need to reference the View in use, it exposes to any view (you want to use) some properties...